# Authenticate to API from Alexa

Tags: authentication, alexa-skills-kit, api-authorization

How would I go about authenticating a user on a smart speaker (Alexa) to my API?

I am thinking of developing a new Alexa "Skill" for my company that would say allow a client in my application to ask their Alexa "Who is my account manager?". I obviously don't want to then ask for their username and password as is spoken out loud so how can I make sure I can retrieve the persons' account in my API that Alexa skill will call?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to do account linking:

> Account linking enables your skill to connect the skill user's Amazon identity with their identity in a different system.

See https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/understand-account-linking.html